# Gradle for multiple fatJars

Tags: java, jar, gradle

I have a gradle build script that looks like this:

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':common:avro')
  ....

fatJar {
  manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'package.subpackage.MainClass'
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to choose which MainClass to use from the command line and possibly also the resulting fat.jar name. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [here](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin) `fatJar` is a regular `jar` task (I assume that You're using this plugin), so You can configure it with standard [DSL](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html), search for `archiveName`. Should be doable.

When it comes to passing command line arguments use `-P` switch to pass the desired class. Then refer to it using `project` variable.